# Assigning a string array position to a string variable

Tags: c++, arrays, postfix-notation

I have a C++ program that I am working on that does a parenthesis check, convert an expression from infix to postfix, evaluates a postfix equation, and does all three at once. I have already completed the parenthesis check.The problem that I am encountering lies within the postfix Evaluation. I started off by reading in a text document containing the equations into the string line array. For instance, line[6] contains "73+9*". Therefore, I was wondering if there is a way to simply let the string temporarily equal each postfix equation.

```
 parentheses tests
x = ((1 + 2)*3
x = (1 + 2))*3
y = (z * j)/(b * 8)^2
postfix equation solving
7 3 + 9 *
5 2 + 1 9 * *
8 9 * 3 5 + -
2 + 8 4 /
infix to postfix conversion
(8 + 4) * 9
(6 + 3) * (2 * 8)
(9 * 8) – (5 + 3)
3 + (9 / 3)
Parentheses check, infix to postfix conversion, postfix evaluation
(8 + 4) * 9
(6 + 3) * (2 * 8)
(9 * 8) – (5 + 3)
3 + (9 / 3)
```

This is the file that I am reading in^^

```
ifstream dataFile;
    dataFile.open("buff.txt");
    string line[20]; //Array to hold data


    //read file into array
    while(dataFile)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            getline(dataFile, line[i]);

        }


    }
    dataFile.close();
```

Above, is the method I used to store the information from text file into an array^^

```
//POSTFIX EVALUATION
            stack<int> operation;
            int operand1, operand2, result, number;
            string input;
            string s;


         for(int k = 5; k < 9; k++)
         {
               input = line[k];//Assigning the postfix Eq to string(?)

            for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
            {


                if (isdigit(input[i]))
                {
                    s = input[i];
                    istringstream iss(s);
                    iss >> number;
                    operation.push(number);

                }
                else
                {
                    operand2 = operation.top();
                    operation.pop();
                    operand1 = operation.top();
                    operation.pop();


                    if(input[i] == '+')
                    {
                        result = operand2 + operand1;
                    }
                    else if(input[i] == '-')
                    {
                        result = operand2 - operand1;
                    }
                    else if(input[i] == '*')
                    {
                        result = operand2 * operand1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = operand2 / operand1;
                    }
                    operation.push(result);

                 }
            }
         cout << "The result is: "<<result<<endl;
        }
```

Lastly, this is my postfix evaluation code^^

Comment: If I understood your question correctly (I'm not sure I have), it should work as-is (that I'm sure). Does it not ?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not.